# float - Positioning tables and pictures

Tags: floats, page-breaking

I want to have a full page table and after it, two full page pictures. But the pictures always appear before the table.

If I try using FloatBarrier, it end up producing a page break after the table with a blank page before two pictures. What can I do to have both pictures right after the table? The code I wrote is the following:

```
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{table}[!htb] 
        (table content here...)
    \end{table}
    \FloatBarrier
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Picture 1}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Picture 2}
\end{landscape}
```

I'm not having both pictures inside a figure block because I don't want them to be listed.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The images will only be listed if you give them a caption, if you put them, in `table` environments the order of the three items will be maintained.

Comment: I must admit I thought of inserting the table without a caption, but I didn't really expected it to work because of the template I was using. However that worked in the end! Many thanks!